# Will magnifying light make it more powerful?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know there is a physics law that says a light magnification can't be more hot than the light source itself, but can it be brighter at the least?

Comment: See this XKCD on Fire from Moonlight. https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation@mmesser314 so basically you can't do what I am trying??

Comment: Also just put this as an answer

Comment: I'm afraid not. I can't put this as an answer. It is just a reference. I didn't add to it.

Comment: Magnifying glasses only focuses the light into a smaller area. The light appears brighter because the intensity has increased, since you now have the **same power** (energy per unit of time) over a **smaller** area:
=/